# OpenCV: minMaxLoc gives no min / max value

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, template-matching, javacpp

I'm trying to follow [OpenCV tutorial on image template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html) using [javacpp-presets](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv).
I want to throw away matches with too low score but `minMaxLoc` seems to not return `minVal` and `maxVal`.

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.DoublePointer;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Mat;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.Point;

import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.CV_32FC1;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.NORM_MINMAX;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.minMaxLoc;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.normalize;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.imread;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.matchTemplate;

public class MatchTemp {

    public static void match(String img, String temp) {

        Mat image = imread(img, IMREAD_COLOR);
        Mat template = imread(temp, IMREAD_COLOR);

        int resultRows = image.rows() - template.rows() + 1;
        int resultCols = image.cols() - template.cols() + 1;
        Mat result = new Mat(resultRows, resultCols, CV_32FC1);

        matchTemplate(image, template, result, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);

        Mat normalizedResult = new Mat();
        normalize(result, normalizedResult, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

        DoublePointer maxVal = new DoublePointer();
        DoublePointer minVal = new DoublePointer();
        Point minLoc = new Point();
        Point maxLoc = new Point();

        minMaxLoc(normalizedResult, minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc, null);

        System.out.println("min: "+minLoc.x()+", "+minLoc.y());
        System.out.println("max: "+maxLoc.x()+", "+maxLoc.y());

        minVal.get(); // this throws exception
        maxVal.get(); // this throws exception
    }
}
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: This pointer address is NULL.
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.DoublePointer.get(Native Method)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.DoublePointer.get(DoublePointer.java:101)
    ...
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i get the score? Do i have to manually check the content of the `Mat`?

Comment: As far as I can see in [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Core.html#minMaxLoc(org.opencv.core.Mat)) it should be something like `result = minMaxLoc(normalizedResult);` and result is type `Core.MinMaxLocResult` or maybe it is a different OpenCV version?

Comment: it's  javacpp-presets: a java wrapper for c++. so the API imitates c++ API. this method returns void

Comment: I see, I have never worked with it. Anyways, there is a high chance that minVal and maxVal are pointers pointing to not a double, but something like nullptr in C++ and maybe it requires to be initialized/allocated somehow. In the documentation it seems that is the case... maybe you can try with `new DoublePointer(1)`. Which allocates 1 double for this pointer

Comment: yep, seems like that's the problem. add the answer, ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that it is trying to access a Null reference. Reading the documentation of [DoublePointer constructor](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/DoublePointer.html#DoublePointer--) which tells to look at [Pointer.Pointer()](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/Pointer.html#Pointer--) it basically tells you the following:

> Default constructor that does nothing.

This means that it is just a pointer similar to C++:

```
double *p;
```

Which does not point to any double, but the documentation tells you that there is another constructor for DoublePointer

```
public DoublePointer(long size)
```

which says that it allocates an array of this size. If size is equal to 1 it is equivalent to say in C++ this is equivalent to:

```
double p[1];
```

or basically

```
double *p = new double;
```

I have never used JavaCpp so if I missed something, please do comment.